# Porqué los rectángulos de la ventana dejan de dibujarse, y como solucionarlo?

Tags: c++, windows

Cuando se ejecuta muchas veces el código que maneja el mensaje WM_KEYDOWN, la ventana deja de dibujar los rectángulos, y al cerrar esa ventana y volverla a abrir, aparece en blanco.

entonces que es lo que provoca que una ventana tenga este comportamiento?

La siguiente función se ejecuta cada 50 ms, la bandera DISPLAY_UPDATE se establece a 1 cada vez que se presiona una tecla o se cambia el tamaño de la ventana.

```
void ManagerTick() {
if (!MDISPLAY_UPDATE) return;
MDISPLAY_UPDATE = 0;
RECT rc;
GetClientRect(MEMORY_WINDOWHANDLER, &rc);
InvalidateRect(MEMORY_WINDOWHANDLER,  &rc, 0);
UpdateWindow(MEMORY_WINDOWHANDLER);
GetClientRect(TopBar, &rc);
InvalidateRect(TopBar,&rc,0);
UpdateWindow(TopBar);}
```

Así se ve la ventana antes de que ocurra el error:
[image]

Y luego de que se repinte unas 20000 veces
se ve así:

[image]

Esta es la función que cuando se ejecuta muchas veces
la pantalla deja de funcionar como debe, quité el código que dibuja para no hacerlo muy largo, ya que solo se llaman FillRect y DrawText.

```
int width  = pps->rcPaint.right - pps->rcPaint.left;
int heigth = pps->rcPaint.bottom - pps->rcPaint.top;

HDC MemoryDC = CreateCompatibleDC(pps->hdc);
HBITMAP MemoryBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(pps->hdc, width, heigth);
SelectObject(MemoryDC, MemoryBitmap);

           // Codigo que dibuja el texto y los rectangulos
           // Para esto no hay nada especial, para esto solo se ejecuta la funcion FillRect y DrawText; no se llama ninguna otra función
           // 



BitBlt(pps->hdc, pps->rcPaint.left, pps->rcPaint.top, width, heigth, MemoryDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
DeleteObject(MemoryBitmap);
DeleteDC(MemoryDC);
DeleteDC(pps->hdc);
```

Comment: Algo no estás liberando y se queda esperando :/

Comment: ¿Crees poder compartir el proyecto o al menos la parte de la ventana? Quizá haya algo que no estamos viendo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estaba ejecutando los FillRect creando una nueva brocha en el segundo argumento, con CreateSolidBrush,
la forma correcta era declararlo fuera de la función
o crearlo como una variable para después poder eliminarlo.